# column names from mysql to csv

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Hey could anyone help me out. I'm creating a csv from mysql table for client side download. The data is inserting and formatting fine to the csv file but no column names? Any help would be much appreciated. I'm new to this so not too much ridicule please :)

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT * FROM score15ans WHERE id_user = "'.$userID.'" ORDER BY pps');
if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
$num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($result);
$headers = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) {
$headers[] = mysqli_fetch_field($result, $i);
}
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if ($fp && $result) {
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');
fputcsv($fp, $headers);
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
}
die;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) {
    $headers[$i] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result, $i);
    $headersField[$i] = $headers[$i]['Field'];
}

fputcsv($fp, $headersField);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering, still no luck with that. It seems to be returning empty values as the first row on the csv is left empty.